# Get list of Azure VM size that supports premium disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I need to fetch a list of Azure vm sizes that supports Premium disk. I tried the 'get-azvmsize' but it does not have a property for 'Premium disk support'.

Command does not give 'premium disk support' property.

```
$data = get-azvmsize -ResourceGroupName Demo-eu-rsv-dev -VMName eusvm1dev

PS /home/cstx_a_manjug> $data

Name                   NumberOfCores MemoryInMB MaxDataDiskCount OSDiskSizeInMB ResourceDiskSizeInMB
----                   ------------- ---------- ---------------- -------------- --------------------
Standard_B1ls                      1        512                2        1047552                 4096
Standard_B1ms                      1       2048                2        1047552                 4096
Standard_B1s                       1       1024                2        1047552                 4096
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [PSVirtualMachineSize Class](http://PSVirtualMachineSize%20Class), there is no such a property for 'Premium disk support'. So I'm afraid that we can't get 'Premium disk support' through this cmd.

Currently we need to use [List Resource SKUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list#lists-all-available-resource-skus-for-the-specified-region) to get the VM size information.

```
{
    "name": "PremiumIO",
    "value": "True"
}
```

This property `PremiumIO` is 'Premium disk support'. Unfortunately only **location** filter is supported currently based on [URI Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list#uri-parameters). So the response data is very large. You need to deal with it in your code to filter "resourceType" as "virtualMachines" and "PremiumIO" as "True".

There is indeed a corresponding Powershell cmd [Get-AzComputeResourceSku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azcomputeresourcesku?view=azps-4.1.0).

Here is an example:

```
Get-AzComputeResourceSku  | where{$_.ResourceType.Equals('virtualMachines') -and $_.Locations.Contains('westus').Equals($true) -and $_.Capabilities.where({($_.Value -eq 'True') -and ($_.Name -eq 'PremiumIO')})}| Select-Object Name, Capabilities, ResourceType, Locations
```